# How can I save the original index after sorting a list?

Tags: python, list, unordered

Let's say I have the following array:

```
a = [4,2,3,1,4]
```

Then I sort it:

```
b = sorted(A) = [1,2,3,4,4]
```

How could I have a list that map where each number was, ex:

```
position(b,a) = [3,1,2,0,4]
```

to clarify this list contains the positions not values)

(ps' also taking in account that first 4 was in position 0)

Comment: You can use numpy's [argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
b = sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda i: i[1])
```

This results is a list of tuples, the first item of which is the original index and second of which is the value:

```
[(3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (0, 4), (4, 4)]
```

Comment: I might be tempted to take it one step further and unpack (if tuples are okay), eg: `orig_pos, b = zip(*sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda i: i[1]))`

Comment: Sure, if the idea is to have two separate lists; but IMO it usually makes more sense to keep data together which belongs together.

Comment: Yup... all depends... just throwing it out there :)

Answer (score 2):

```py
def position(a):
    return sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda k: a[k])
```