# Python sort array and it's label array

Tags: python

I need to sort boxes array from top left to bottom right, and I am using the solution here [How can I sort contours from left to right and top to bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654302/how-can-i-sort-contours-from-left-to-right-and-top-to-bottom). Which works fine. But I have another array which keep the box label,  I need to use this label after sorting tmp_box array. So how can sort `box_label` or keep the original index of `tmp_box` like this [How can I save the original index after sorting a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969987/how-can-i-save-the-original-index-after-sorting-a-list) which I can use to access the `box_label`.

```
box_label = ["box1","box2","box3"]
tmp_box = []
tmp_box.append([100,90,20,30]) #x,y,w,h
tmp_box.append([90,80,25,30]) #x,y,w,h
tmp_box.append([190,180,25,30]) #x,y,w,h

tmp_box_np = np.array(tmp_box)
max_height = np.max(tmp_box_np[::, 3])
nearest = max_height * 1.4
tmp_box.sort(key=lambda r: [int(nearest * round(float(r[1]) / nearest)), r[0]])
```

Comment: I don't understand why the questions your read and linked don't already answer the question.

Comment: Could you include a sample of desired output?

Comment: Strongly recommend not using the "parallel arrays" approach, but rather something like:  `boxes = [("box1", [100, 90, 20, 30]), ...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are tones of ways to do it,

**1. inserting the name in the list:**

```py
box_list = [[100, 90, 20, 30, "box1"],
            [90, 80, 25, 30, "box2"]
            [190, 180, 25, 30, "box3"]]
# your code won't change but the name is linked to the properties
```

**2. using a lib:**

ps: only works if all boxes are different!!!

```py
box_labels = ["box1", "box2", "box3"]
box_properties = [
    [100,90,20,30],
    [90,80,25,30],
    [190,180,25,30] 
]

l = {}

for i in range(len(box_labels)):
    l[str(box_properties[i])] = box_labels[i]

box_prop = box_properties[0]

return l[box_prop]
#return box1
```

**3. using a class:**

```py
class box:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.label = l
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

# when sorting, use lambda box : (box.x, box.y, box.w, box.h)
```

All solutions are viable, just pick the one that fit your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can do what [has been suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60970028/12233224) (and you have already refered to):
use `sorted` with `enumerate`.

In code:

```py
box_labels = ["box1", "box2", "box3"]
box_properties = [
    [100,90,20,30],
    [90,80,25,30],
    [190,180,25,30] 
]

max_height = max([properties[3] for properties in box_properties])
nearest = max_height * 1.4

sorted_index_boxes = sorted(enumerate(box_properties), key=lambda r: int(nearest * round(float(r[1][1]))))

print(sorted_index_boxes)
```

NOTE: I've renamed variables to improve readability and removed `numpy` since I don't think is necessary for this small example.

This outputs:

```
[(1, [90, 80, 25, 30]), (0, [100, 90, 20, 30]), (2, [190, 180, 25, 30])]
```

You can then use the indexes to get the box labels.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by keeping a copy of `tmp_box` before sorting, to an array `tmp_box_original`

Then using `arry.index()` get the index like,

```
for box in tmp_box:
    index = tmp_box_original.index(box)
```